# Ubuntu wifi not connecting

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an old laptop. Ever since I upgraded it (wiped it and put on a fresh install), i can't connect to wifi. Unfortunately, I can not connect it to an Ethernet cable at the momment, however, I have a win7 PC I can use. I downloaded the .deb driver onto the PC, and moved it over via a USB. I had to run the deb through terminal (Ubuntu Software center didn't like it) in order to get the firmware. I rebooted my computer, and it no longer says "firmware missing", however it can't find any of the networks, and now says "No network devices available" has anybody found a fix?

PS I'm using the Broadcam-sta-common deb.

Comment: Execute in terminal the following commands and paste it here. 
`sudo lspci`and `ifconfig`

Comment: @revnoise I typed the first one in and got a bunch of stuff.  Let me copy the important stuff... '02:00.0 Ethernet controller:  Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)'

Comment: @revnoise  cancel
hide help

Answer (score 0):

For Wifi devices :

Install common device drivers :

```
sudo apt-get install collectd-core collectd-dev collectd-dbg collectd-utils
```

Install Wifi Network manager:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk wicd wicd-daemon wicd-curses wicd-cli
```