# "Enable Wifi" Option Gone

Tags: wireless, 13.10

So my wifi was disabled (I couldn't select the "enable wifi" option) and wouldn't automatically connect to wifi sometimes. I ran this command after reading that it did the trick for someone

```
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

but now the option is gone altogether and it still won't connect!
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with the applications and the drivers in this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/393299/224082)

Answer (score 0):

Have you check /etc/network/interfaces setting. I sometime lost enable wifi option by editing this file for some reason.

But you can use:

> sudo ifup

For me wireless interface is wlan0 then I run.

> sudo ifup wlan0

Issue **ifconfig** to list all your network interfaces.